# How to loop changing text with HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the code i've found :

```
<script>
    var example = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

    textSequence(0);
    function textSequence(i) {

        if (example.length > i) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = example[i];
                textSequence(++i);
            }, 3000); // 3 seconds (in milliseconds)

        } else if (example.length == i) { // Loop
            textSequence(0);
        }

    }
</script>
```

And the div to show the sequence

```
<div id="sequence"></div>
```

What I would like to change is :

1. To show the first text instantly on page load instead of 3 seconds later.
2. To have a slide in / slide out effect transition

How can I do that?

Comment: For the first request, you could move the line starting with `document` just above the first `if`. The second one is too broad. There are many ways to do this, with lots of libraries available.

Comment: <script>
    var example = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

    textSequence(0);
    function textSequence(i) {

document.getElementById("sequence").innerHTML = example[i];

        if (example.length > i) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                textSequence(++i);
            }, 3000); // 3 seconds (in milliseconds)

        } else if (example.length == i) { // Loop
            textSequence(0);
        }

    }
</script>

Like this? @Xufox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a bit, so it'll start right away.
For the slide in and out, you're better off using jQuery, instead of pure Javascript.

```
<script>
    var example = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
    var gFirstTime = true;
    textSequence(0);


    function textSequence(i) {
        if (gFirstTime) {
            timeToWait = 0;
            gFirstTime = false;
        }
        else {
            timeToWait = 3000;
        }
        if (example.length > i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var sequenceDiv = document.getElementById("sequence");                                                          
                sequenceDiv.innerHTML = example[i];                    
                textSequence(++i);
            }, timeToWait); // 3 seconds (in milliseconds)

        } else if (example.length == i) { // Loop
            textSequence(0);
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: you're welcome!  Good luck with the slideIn/Out.

Comment: If this answer helps you, can you mark the answer up?  thanks!